# How to send a JWT Token to the Header in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, jwt

I am creating an application that will create a User Session in conjunction with MySQL on Node.js.

I followed the tutorial for the link below and have trouble using the JWT Token.

I get a "Please send a token" error if I make a POST /registration request through Postman. I checked the Header through the search, but my Authorization in the Header list is not checked.

I just followed the tutorial and it is sad that it does not work.

**Routes/Users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var users = express.Router();
var database = require('../Database/database');
var cors = require('cors')
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var token;

users.use(cors());

process.env.SECRET_KEY = "devesh";

users.post('/register', function(req, res) {

    var today = new Date();
    var appData = {
        "error": 1,
        "data": ""
    };
    var userData = {
        "first_name": req.body.first_name,
        "last_name": req.body.last_name,
        "email": req.body.email,
        "password": req.body.password,
        "created": today
    }

    database.connection.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            appData["error"] = 1;
            appData["data"] = "Internal Server Error";
            res.status(500).json(appData);
        } else {
            connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', userData, function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (!err) {
                    appData.error = 0;
                    appData["data"] = "User registered successfully!";
                    res.status(201).json(appData);
                } else {
                    appData["data"] = "Error Occured!";
                    res.status(400).json(appData);
                }
            });
            connection.release();
        }
    });
});

users.post('/login', function(req, res) {

    var appData = {};
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    database.connection.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            appData["error"] = 1;
            appData["data"] = "Internal Server Error";
            res.status(500).json(appData);
        } else {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    appData.error = 1;
                    appData["data"] = "Error Occured!";
                    res.status(400).json(appData);
                } else {
                    if (rows.length > 0) {
                        if (rows[0].password == password) {
                            let token = jwt.sign(rows[0], process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                                expiresIn: 1440
                            });
                            appData.error = 0;
                            appData["token"] = token;
                            res.status(200).json(appData);
                        } else {
                            appData.error = 1;
                            appData["data"] = "Email and Password does not match";
                            res.status(204).json(appData);
                        }
                    } else {
                        appData.error = 1;
                        appData["data"] = "Email does not exists!";
                        res.status(204).json(appData);
                    }
                }
            });
            connection.release();
        }
    });
});

users.post('/login', function(req, res) {

    var appData = {};
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    database.connection.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            appData["error"] = 1;
            appData["data"] = "Internal Server Error";
            res.status(500).json(appData);
        } else {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    appData.error = 1;
                    appData["data"] = "Error Occured!";
                    res.status(400).json(appData);
                } else {
                    if (rows.length > 0) {
                        if (rows[0].password == password) {
                            token = jwt.sign(rows[0], process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                                expiresIn: 5000
                            });
                            appData.error = 0;
                            appData["token"] = token;
                            res.status(200).json(appData);
                        } else {
                            appData.error = 1;
                            appData["data"] = "Email and Password does not match";
                            res.status(204).json(appData);
                        }
                    } else {
                        appData.error = 1;
                        appData["data"] = "Email does not exists!";
                        res.status(204).json(appData);
                    }
                }
            });
            connection.release();
        }
    });
});

users.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var token = req.body.token || req.headers['token'];
    var appData = {};
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                appData["error"] = 1;
                appData["data"] = "Token is invalid";
                res.status(500).json(appData);
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        appData["error"] = 1;
        appData["data"] = "Please send a token";
        res.status(403).json(appData);
    }
});

users.get('/getUsers', function(req, res) {

    var appData = {};

    database.connection.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            appData["error"] = 1;
            appData["data"] = "Internal Server Error";
            res.status(500).json(appData);
        } else {
            connection.query('SELECT *FROM users', function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (!err) {
                    appData["error"] = 0;
                    appData["data"] = rows;
                    res.status(200).json(appData);
                } else {
                    appData["data"] = "No data found";
                    res.status(204).json(appData);
                }
            });
            connection.release();
        }
    });
});

module.exports = users;
```

**Server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

var Users = require('./Routes/Users');

app.use('/users',Users);

app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log("Server is running on port: "+port);
});
```

**Postman Header**

[image]

Comment: Can you send _anything_ in the header to your Node application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is my code. I'm using axios

```
export function Post(url, data) {
  const authHeader = initAuthHeaders();
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + authHeader
    }
  };

  return axios.post(url, data, config);
}
```

Full source code can be found [here](https://github.com/Awesome-CMS-Core/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/React/js/App/Helper/Http.js#L25)

Comment: axios is a library unfamiliar to me. And your code is so different from the code I wrote. It does not help me T_T

Comment: try to convert from users.post to axios post will do the trick

Comment: you saved my time, bro. I was trying to send with a different header called "x-auth-token" which I learnt from a tutorial course, instead...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Postman header with token]

Here I added this snippet for adding the token in header.After login take token data and add into header for your request like token as key and token data as value.

Answer (score 0):

**This might be help you**

```
middleware.loadUser= (req, res, next) => {
  const { headers } = req;

  if (_.isEmpty(headers.authorization)) {
    //auth error
  } else {
    const decoded = jwt.decodeAuthToken(headers.authorization.replace('Bearer ', ''));
    if (decoded) {
      User.findOne({ _id: decoded.id })
        .then((user) => {
          if (user) {
          } else {
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {

        });
      req.user = decoded;
    } else {
    }
  }
};
```